# Django Postgres ArrayField(models.IntegerField) migration error

Tags: python, django-models

I am new to Django and my aim is to store a list of integers in Django model using `ArrayField` but when I run migrations it gives the following error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "object_ids" is of type integer[] but default expression is of type integer
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

The field that i am using is:

```
ids=ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), null=True, blank=True)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
# Create your models here.
class YourModel(models.Model):
    ids = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(),null=True, blank=True)
```

More information here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

Comment: I am doing this already i am importing it first and then making it a field of  a model

Comment: Hmm, you have generated the migrations with "python manage.py makemigrations" and then "python manage.py migrate" ? -- 
can you show me your models.py?